# SFMC Automation Studio Email Activity running (not errored) for over 12 hours

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, automationstudio

I have an automation that includes 2 email sends in step 4 and 2 email sends in step 5. The automation was activated about 18 hours ago and all of step 4 executed, and one of the email send activities in step 5 is complete but the second email send activity in step 5 still says sending. What are some reasons that an email activity could say "sending" still when the other activity in the same step has successfully completed?

Comment: If I were to guess... it's an email scripting problem.  I'd open a support ticket.

Comment: I’m with Adam on this one.. do you by any chance retrieve any data directly from Salesforce using AMPscript inside the email or in the sender profile?

Comment: Not sure if STO in automations was around at this time, but I had this problem and realized it's because I set STO to 24 hours, so it would seem the automation doesn't finish until that window closes or all emails have been sent. In my case, I could go into tracking and see that the send wasn't full finished.